# Where is the master destruction spell at?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In skyrim i have 100 skill in the destruction school, so I went to does a destruction teacher in the College of Winterhold. She gave me a book that is suppose to lead me to the master destruction spell, but I can't figure out where it is. The book is in a riddle and i can't figure it out. Has anyone done it and can tell me where to go?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This quest is called [Destruction Ritual Spell](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Destruction_Ritual_Spell) and is given by Faralda.

There are actually several riddles in a row you have to solve in order to complete this quest.  The first one will take you to [Windward Ruins](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Windward_Ruins) southwest of Dawnstar.

If you don't want to bother solving the rest, you can always [look them up at the UESP page for this quest.](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Destruction_Ritual_Spell):

> 1. Talk to Faralda, who will give you a book.
> 2. Visit Windward Ruins, activate the pedestal and cast a fire spell on it.
> 3. Visit North Skybound Watch, same as before, but casting a frost spell.
> 4. Visit Four Skull Lookout, same as before, but casting a shock spell.
> 5. Learn the spell contained within the book.

Comment: Its not that i don't want to solve them its just it wouldn't take forever i probably would have never guess any of those

Comment: @jasonvalderrama, yeah man.  I went to the wiki myself.  Too much trying to figure crap out, not enough swording things in the face. :)

Comment: It may be a good idea to use novice spells on the pedestals(flames, frostbite, sparks) so as to avoid potential glitches.

Answer (score 3):

The [quest](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Destruction_Ritual_Spell) marker and/or clues should be leading you to three locations, in order:

- [Windward Ruins](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Windward_Ruins), which is South-West of Dawnstar
- [Skybound Watch Pass](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Skybound_Watch_Pass), between Falkreath and Whiterun. There are two map markers for the entrances, labeled "North Skybound Watch" and "South Skybound Watch"
- [Four Skull Lookout](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Four_Skull_Lookout), South of Karthwasten.

At each, there will be a pedestal, where you will have to put the book, and cast a destruction spell of the appropriate element on it.

Comment: It may be a good idea to use novice spells on the pedestals(flames, frostbite, sparks) so as to avoid potential glitches.